# VK SDK android "sdk_fingerprint is incorrect" error

Tags: android, vk-sdk

I'm using official VK SDK for Android and currently I am trying to authorize a user via official VK app from Google Play Market. I have no errors when authorizing with login web page that pops up and asks for user's credentials, but if the app is installed it will send an intent to launch auth window in the app and it gives me that error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYoWm.jpg

I am initializing the SDK, tried to get the fingerprint both using the Android Studio terminal and VKSDK method. Both return the same, but it doesn't work. Package name is copied to the settings of my VK app, no main activity is provided because it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by recreating debug.keystore in ~/.android/ folder and creating new keystores along with fingerprints for debug and release version.

Answer (score 9):

My problem was in having certificate fingerprint defined in application options (in the developer console on the vk.com) just as it was printed out by keytool while the documentation states to remove colons. Should I leave there hex digits only, the problem got resolved immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and release versions of the application will have different fingerprints as they get signed using different keystores. One is android debug keystore, thr other is your release keystore. Make sure you have both fingerprints listed in your VK settings.

Then, on different machines debug keystores will differ, too, so if you're using several machines you have to add fingerprints for every machine.